# How to upload files and folders to jenkins server

Tags: ios, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have created a jenkins server in Mac OS X, and have iOS application project files in windows machine(not configured anything in windows machine) here want to achieve the below points.

1. Have to upload the iOS application projects into mac os x jenkins
   server
2. Create a job for that uploaded project
3. have to build that project.
4. download the package files into windows machine

is this possible to achieve using jenkins framework?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible

the easiest way is to:

1. use git to upload project from windows to some git server (ex. github.com or your own installation on OsX machine)
2. configure jenkins job to use git repository you've created and add proper build step
3. use 'Publish Over CIFS' plugin to push build result to windows share